# Como adicionar um objeto dentro do stdClass() e imprimir o json

Tags: php, sql, json

Como faço para adicionar uma variavel ou objeto dentro de um json. Esta imprimindo assim meu json:

```
{"Registros":[{"RegistroOperacaoID":"39","Tipo":"11","DataOperacao":"2019-03-27 16:29:36","AlunoID":null,"ResponsavelID":"57","CursoID":"327","MatriculaID":null,"PlanoID":"68","Processado":"0","Nome":null}
```

gostaria de acrescentar juntos com esses dados mais uma variavel ou objeto, que ficaria dessa forma:

```
{"Registros":[{"RegistroOperacaoID":"39","Tipo":"11","DataOperacao":"2019-03-27 16:29:36","AlunoID":null,"ResponsavelID":"57","CursoID":"327","MatriculaID":null,"PlanoID":"68","Processado":"0","variavel":"1 registro","Nome":null}
```

meu codigo php esta assim:

registro.operacao.php

```
$sql = "SELECT R.RegistroOperacaoID, R.Tipo, R.DataOperacao, R.AlunoID, R.ResponsavelID, R.CursoID, R.MatriculaID, R.PlanoID, R.Processado, A.Nome FROM {$pfx}Registrooperacoes R LEFT JOIN {$pfx}Aluno A ON (A.AlunoID = R.AlunoID) WHERE Processado = 0";

    $qry = $database->query($sql);
    $listaOperacoes = array();
    $ctaOperacoes = 0;
    if($qry){
        while ($row = fetch($qry)) {
            $listaOperacoes[] = $row;            
            $ctaOperacoes++;           
        }
    }

    @$output = new StdClass();
    //$variavel = "$ctaOperacoes registros";        
    $output->Registros = $listaOperacoes;    

    $saida = json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $saida;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para adicionar um valor é simples, mas você não adiciona direto no json, perceba que no seu código esta criando um objeto e a variavel `$saida` esta recebendo este objeto convertido em json, o que precisamos fazer é colocar novo atributo ou objeto dentro de `$output` antes de imprimir o json.
Aonde vamos trabalhar em seu código.

```
    @$output = new StdClass();
    //$variavel = "$ctaOperacoes registros";

    //Vamos trabalhar aqui

    $output->Registros = $listaOperacoes;

    $saida = json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $saida;
```

A `$listaOperacoes` é um array de objetos, então para fazer a inserção precisamos ter a chave(`$key`) de cada item, sendo assim o `foreach` nós ajudara a resolver o problema.
O `novoAtributo` (pode ter qualquer nome) é o atributo que estamos criando dentro de um objeto da `$listaOperacoes`. A forma de se colocar esta nova variavel é a seguinte.

```
    foreach ($listaOperacoes as $key => $value) {
        $listaOperacoes[$key]->novoAtributo = 'Eu sou um novo valor dentro do registro';
    }
```

Seu código deve ficar da seguinte forma amigo.

```
    @$output = new StdClass();
    //$variavel = "$ctaOperacoes registros";    

    foreach ($listaOperacoes as $key => $value) {
        $listaOperacoes[$key]->novoAtributo = 'Eu sou um novo valor dentro do 
    registro';
    }

    $output->Registros = $listaOperacoes;    

    $saida = json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $saida;
```

Comment: Olá amigo, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! explicação perfeita.

Comment: Obrigado, uma boa forma de você ajudar a outros com sua dúvida é sinalizar que esta resposta foi a que resolveu o seu problema.